# Custom actionLayout not showing in NavDrawer item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm having some trouble using custom views for a menu item in a nav drawer. When I use `android:actionLayout` nothing changes, despite having a valid layout. The item text shows, but nothing from the custom layout is showing. From what I've read in the documentation, I shouldn't need any java code for this, and should be able to set it purely in xml, right?

My activity drawer and actionLayout xml files are as follows:

`activity_main_drawer.xml` file:

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="none" >
    <item ... />
    <item ... />
    <item ... />
</group>

<group android:id="@+id/menu_bottom" android:checkableBehavior="none">
    <item ... />
</group>

<group android:id="@+id/bookmark_list" android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_bookmark"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/nav_bookmark_header_layout"
        android:title="Some text"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</group>
```

`layout/nav_bookmark_header_layout.xml` file:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/counterView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Custom text"/>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ahh, found it. `android:actionLayout` should be `app:actionLayout`

Answer (score 0):

A layout to use as the action view. `app:actionLayout` you should use it is Introduced in API Level 11.